# ZSH command history not saved after terminal restart

Tags: terminal, zsh, macos

Whenever I restart my terminal, I can't use the arrow key to see previous commands I've typed into terminal. I was able to do this previously. Since I updated to macOS Catalina and used Apple's default ZSH every time I restart terminal there is no command history.

My zshrc file uses the following configurations to save commands:

```
# History in cache directory:
HISTSIZE=10000
SAVEHIST=10000
HISTFILE=~/.cache/zsh/history
setopt INC_APPEND_HISTORY
setopt SHARE_HISTORY
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is likely that the directory `~/.cache/zsh/` doesn't exist. Zsh will create the hist file for you if it doesn't exist, but it will not create non-existent dirs for you.

There's two solutions, depending on what you prefer:

- Remove the line where you set `$HISTFILE`. On macOS, you don't need to set it (unless you want to change it from the default), because this is already done for you in `/etc/zshrc`.
- Create the dir where you want Zsh to write the file.

As an aside, if you use any of the [`HIST_*_DUPS` options](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#History), you should make sure `$HISTSIZE` is always at least 20% bigger than `$SAVEHIST`. Otherwise, Zsh is not able to effectively eliminate duplicates  once your history exceeds `$SAVEHIST`. So, in your case, I would increase it to `HISTSIZE=12000` or greater.

Comment: Thank you Marlon! commenting out the HISTFILE was the solution also, thank you for describing the issue :)

Comment: You're welcome. 